# bam() error: "reparameterization unstable for margin: not done"

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

In running a large GAM model of the form

```
mgcv::bam(y ~ te(x, y, k = 100, bs = 'ts'),
          family = binomial,
          discrete = TRUE)
```

I get this warning

```
Warning message:
In smooth.construct.tensor.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) :
  reparameterization unstable for margin: not done
```

and the resultant smooth are wild and clearly not fitted correctly.

This does not occur with `"cs"` smooths.  I have been unable to determine if it occurs with `discrete = FALSE` as that takes much longer to run.  Notably, the distribution of `x` is highly skewed.

What does this warning mean and how can it be ameliorated?

I note my `x` data (~200K values) are highly skewed. Positive `y` values are only ~7%. For `"ts"` and `"tp"` smooths with large data, `mgcv` chooses `max.knots` points (2000 by default) from which to construct a full thin-plate spline before truncating to `k`. So I suspect that these points are inadequate for constructing the spline.  One can supply these initial points by providing a `knots` value greater than `k`, but what would be a good approach to selecting these candidate knots?

Comment: Hey Noam, did you ever figure out what happened here?